# Rails: Simple Form checkbox and material design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, material-design, simple-form

I have been trying to figure out how to make simple form generate the correct code for a checkbox.

**The code im trying to create is:**

```
<div class="checkbox m-b-15">
  <input value="0" type="hidden" name="group[open]">
  <label>
    <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="group[open]" id="group_open">
    <i class="input-helper"></i>
    Label text
  </label>
</div>
```

**So far im managed to generate**

```
<div class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="group[open]">
  <label class="boolean optional" for="group_open">
  <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="group[open]" id="group_open">
    Label text
  </label>
</div>
```

**With the following code**

```
b.wrapper tag: :label do |ba|
  ba.use :input

  # <i class="input-helper"></i> tag should go here

  ba.use :label_text
end
```

So how do I insert then i tag?

```
<i class="input-helper"></i>
```